# using jquery for validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm pretty much new to jquery. I've been trying to do validations where i check if a textbox length is greater than 4.

So, this is what i did:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tbstreet1').blur(isValid);
                        });
   function isValid()
{
    Boolean isvalid;
   var street1Length = $("#tbstreet1").val().length;

   alert(street1Length);
     if(myLength >4)
     {
         isvalid= true;
        ActivateSave()
     }


}
function ActivateSave()
    {

   $("#btn_save").attr("Enabled",true);
   }
```

This is my aspx page:

```
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="street1" Text="Street1" O></asp:Label> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbstreet1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"  ></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="btn_save" runat="server" Text="Save" Enabled="false" />
```

I even have script source in my .net page

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"  type="text/javascript" > 
 </script>
```

But the thing has been that how do i call the javascript function from here? as i 'm pretty sure that my javascript is not getting called. Can u help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'attach' your jQuery function to your textbox:

```
$('#tbstreet1').blur(isValid);
```

This will run the `isValid` function when the text field is blurred. Alternatively, you can provide an anonymous function:

```
$('#tbstreet1').blur(function() {
    // do something, maybe even 'isValid();'
});
```

This is good if the code you need to run is one-off, but if you need the function to be executed multiple times in multiple places, it's better to create a 'named' function, like in the first example.

Keep in mind that you need to put all this code inside the `onReady` function, which will execute only after the page is finished loading (and the DOM is ready for navigation). You can do this by simply using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // this is a shortcut for $(document).ready()
    $(function() {
        // your code
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget that needs to be in a `.load()` or `.ready()` handler. Or at least called after that element in the page load.

Comment: Heh Jared, I was editing my answer when you posted that comment :).

Comment: Hey I did this .. I'll just update my code in a second but still it doesn't work for me..so can u please help me

Comment: My guess is that it's the `<asp:TextBox ID="tbstreet1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>`. I don't use ASP.NET myself, so you'll have to look at what HTML is being created, and which element the `tbstreet1` ID is being set on. jQuery can only act on HTML elements. You may need to do something like `$('#tbstreet1 input').blur(isValid);`.

Comment: k... Let me check the source and test it...give me  a miute

Comment: Are you worrying about server-side validation? Remember that a malicious user could disable javascript and submit a value with length < 4. Also, have you considered "trimming" the response? You may be getting a response that's 4 spaces otherwise. :-) Just trying to add some helpful tips

Comment: No just an assignment trying to learn jquery..... my first code in jquery........

Comment: hey its not going into jquery function.. I added  a alert inside Onready function.alert is not displayed

Comment: yeah i got the concept but somehow in asp.net i've been not getting that

Comment: Only way then is to look at the generated HTML source code and figure out what it's doing there. You can also use IE's Developer Tools (press F12) or Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) if you use Firefox to see what the Javascript is doing behind the scenes (the console tab is what you want to look at).

Comment: @daniel can u help me with this i'm gonna paste the source in jsfiddle if u'r free

Comment: We should move this to chat, but we need to add enough comments first for the link to pop up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3511/discussion-between-daniel-t-and-user838359)

Answer (score 0):

just to add to @Daniel T.'s answer:

The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus, to have a more accurate text change event you can use [this](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) plugin

I suggest you to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to make js debug, it makes things much easier

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you havent made the change, if you are running your textbox at server you do need

```
 $('#<%= tbstreet1.ClientID %>').blur(function(){});
```

instead of

```
 $('#tbstreet1').blur(function(){});
```